# delete a object in numpy 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want only the desired [1,2] to be deleted, but this is not done

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3]])
arr = np.delete(arr, np.where(np.isin(arr, [[1,2]])))

print(arr)
```

output: array([3, 5, 6, 1, 3])

I also used the setdiff1d method, but it removed all 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you didn't spend much time reading the `np.delete` docs.  You didn't specify an axis.

```
In [96]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3]])
```

Removing the first row is easy:

```
In [97]: np.delete(arr, 0, axis=0)
Out[97]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
```

Without axis,`delete` flattens the array first:

```
In [98]: np.delete(arr, 0, )
Out[98]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3])
```

It's also easy to remove/select rows by indexing, or boolean masking

```
In [99]: arr[[1,2,3],:]
Out[99]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
```

That's ultimately what `delete` does; it translates the "remove" list into a "keep" list.

The other part of your problem is identifing which rows you want to remove.  That is, converting values into row indices.  It's a good idea to keep the two tasks separate.

Exploring the use of `isin`

```
In [100]: np.isin(arr, [[1,2]])
Out[100]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]])
```

This is a 2d boolean array.  Applying `all`:

```
In [101]: np.isin(arr, [[1,2]]).all(axis=0)
Out[101]: array([False, False])
```

oops, wrong axis:

```
In [102]: np.isin(arr, [[1,2]]).all(axis=1)
Out[102]: array([ True, False, False, False])
```

we can use that boolean array index the rows:

```
In [103]: arr[np.isin(arr, [[1,2]]).all(axis=1),:]
Out[103]: array([[1, 2]])
```

and for removing a row:

```
In [104]: arr[~np.isin(arr, [[1,2]]).all(axis=1),:]
Out[104]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
```

Yes, we could use `where` to convert that to an index, but it isn't needed.

I encourage you to examine and understand each piece in the process, both identifying the values, and removing them.  Don't treat any as a 'block box' that you don't need to understand.

Comment: so, the problem with `isin` here is that it will treate `[1,2]` the same as `[2,1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I used `isin` because the OP used it.  I didn't consdier the possibility that it would catch [2,1] as well.  Normally I would use simple equality, `(arr==[1,2]).all(1)` for this kind of testing.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps?

```
mask = (arr[:,0] == 1) & (arr[:,1] == 2)
# where first column == 1 and 2nd column == 2
# invert the mask and select all the rows where this is not true
print(arr[~mask])
```

here is the output from your example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3]])
>>> mask = (arr[:,0] == 1) & (arr[:,1] == 2)
>>> mask
array([ True, False, False, False])
>>> arr[~mask]
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
>>>
```

Comment: What if there are several options?

Comment: what is your expected output for `[[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],...]` if you tell it to remove [1,2] ? its not at all clear in your question what you expect... but this will remove all of them ... its easy enough to fix to only remove the first or the last or a random one or whatever

Comment: I mean, for example, removing two options [1,2] and [3,4].

Comment: you could call it a second time or you could do something like `mask = mask | ( (arr[:,0] == 3) & (arr[:,1] == 4))` I guess? ... you could probably abstract it into a method ...

Comment: It's a good solution, but what if there are more options?

Answer (score 0):

So, for this particular case, I suggest using a structured view of your array, this allows you to treat it like an "array of objects" (of *structs*):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3]])
>>> structured = arr.ravel().view("i8, i8")
>>> structured
array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (1, 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Then, you can simply do:

```
>>> np.isin(structured, np.array([(1,2)], dtype="i8, i8"))
array([ True, False, False, False])
>>> arr[np.isin(structured, np.array([(1,2)], dtype="i8, i8"))]
array([[1, 2]])
>>> arr[~np.isin(structured, np.array([(1,2)], dtype="i8, i8"))]
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
```

Or equivalently using `np.delete` specifying the correct axis:

```
>>> np.delete(arr, np.isin(structured, np.array([(1,2)], dtype="i8, i8")), axis=0)
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 3]])
```

Important to note, you can add more "items" to delete trivially:

```
>>> np.delete(arr, np.isin(structured, np.array([(1,2), (5,6)], dtype="i8, i8")), axis=0)
array([[3, 4],
       [1, 3]])
```

Just make sure you use a `list` with `tuple`'s when you create the structured array using the `np.array` constructor, so that it understands how you want them interpreted correctly.